# Is there a way to extract something between two tags in python in a text file?

Tags: python, python-re

```
======AD_START======

ABC

XYZ

EFG

======AD_END======
```

I want to extract ABC, XYZ and EFG together.

I've tried using the following, but neither worked:

```
re.findall(r'======AD_START======(.*?)======AD_END======', book)
```

```
re.search(r'======AD_START======(.*?)======AD_END======', book)
```

Comment: "*neither worked*" - Can you elaborate on how exactly it "didn't work"? Please include any error messages you encountered with these attempts, along with the expected outcome and actual outcomes.

Comment: @esqew I appreciate your effort to improve a question's readability through an edit, but I do not think it's appropriate to edit the actual code, in particular your edit of `(.?)` into `(.*?)` rendered confusion for people reading my answer.

Comment: @esqew *If you change the code in a question, you may accidentally remove the bug that causes the problem.* [How do I make a good edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220/2359945)  You are obviously not new here, so could you help me understand?

Comment: @RazzleShazl I find it a bit quick that you’ve jumped to the conclusion that I don’t know how to make a constructive edit as I actually have not changed any of the OP’s original code. The asterisks you’re referring to were provided by the OP in their question but were interpreted as Markdown by Stack Overflow’s parser. You can verify this by simply looking at the edit summary in “Side-by-side Markdown” view that I have not at all changed the substance of the OP’s question.

Comment: @esqew Hey thanks for explaining and I'm sorry for coming across as implying that you do not know how to make a constructive edit.  I think I acknowledged that you are senior here.  That's why I asked you to *help me understand*.  This is my first time encountering this markdown issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [python slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html) along with the [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) method:

`file.txt`:

```
======AD_START======

ABC

XYZ

EFG

======AD_END======
```

Here is the way of doing it:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = f.read()

start = "======AD_START======"
end = "======AD_END======"

print(s[s.index(start) + len(start): s.index(end)])
```

Output:

```
ABC

XYZ

EFG
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `.` to blow past `\n` boundaries (end of each line) so you should pass [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) as a flag to `search`.  Also, [`?`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) means "zero or one".

```
book = '''
======AD_START======

ABC

XYZ

EFG

======AD_END======
'''
    
import re
precise = re.search(r'======AD_START======(.+?)======AD_END======', book, re.DOTALL)
print('*'*80)
print(precise.group(1))
print('*'*80)
```

Output:

```
********************************************************************************


ABC

XYZ

EFG


********************************************************************************
```

Note for the case that if there is nothing between `AD_START` and `AD_END` lines, this will still generate a result with 2 empty lines.  I am not sure exactly what your parsing requirements are, but this solves your question.

Comment: `.*?` mean "0 or more non-greedy" in this case, not "0 or 1".  Perhaps the OP has multiple tagged sections in the file.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @MarkTolonen.  The original question was `.?` and (inappropriately) got fixed with an edit by @esqew

Comment: The edit by @esqew did shed light on my answer missing a non-greedy `?` modifier, thanks for that.  Updated answer.  WIthout the non-greedy modifier, then if there were 2 `AD_END` tags in the file, it would grab too much.